# Rails 3 pagination, will_paginate vs. Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I'm looking into a pagination solution for my app and saw that there is a new-ish gem `Kaminari` compared to the trusty `will_paginate`. It looks like `will_paginate` wasn't updated for awhile but has since came back with V3.0. What's the consensus, is one preferred over the other and why? Thanks in advance for your insights.

**EDIT**

I asked Ryan Bates on Twitter and he said

> Both do the job equally well. The biggest factor is if you use any
>   gems which require pagination since they are incompatible. I do like
>   will_paginate's non-engine approach a bit more, but that's a personal
>   preference.

Answer (score 26):

[Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) Rocks if you are using rails 3+ , I like to use it because

1. It is latest library and supports rails 3+ powerfully.
2. 'Kaminari' is Easy to use and it supports `ajax` very easily.
3. Paginate pure **Object** way.
4. It works as a proxy on AREL, no specific paginate method overloaded on ActiveRecord
5. Does not pollute the Array or Hash object
6. More standard rails support for other view formats, **most important mobile**

   ```
   User.page(7).per(50)
   ```

   But if you are using rails 2.3 etc. keep stick with [will_paginate](http://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) that also works with rails 3 +, but internally its not such perfect as Kaminari code.

Answer (score 19):

I really like Kaminari. I don't know if will_paginate does this, but Kaminari also can paginate any regular old `Array`:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(an_array).page params[:page]
```

There are [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) for both, which I recommend watching.

Answer (score 14):

watch the [kaminari railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) an then watch the [will paginate railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate-revised?view=comments)

Ryan Bates advises in the comments that Kaminari makes heavier use of partials, which might make it fractionally slower, but not much

Comment: regarding performance: browsing through 100k+ entries makes will_paginate unuseable slow. kaminari however stays fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both Gems, and frankly, I like Kaminari better. It's so easy to use. I haven't seen any performance issues or environment issues (my app lives on Heroku).

Answer (score 1):

While will_paginate does the job pretty quickly, Kaminari also allow you to quickly edit the pagination HTML output.

This was a great thing for me, since i am using Bootstrap 3, and wanted to use the default paginations styles.

There is a gem for will_paginate that allows you to do the same, but Kaminari it's much more flixible